# Page redirect after flush() - if user click CANCEL in SaveAs dialog (PHP)

Tags: php

I was looking on many sites but I found no working solution. So I would like to aks for help here, thank you all for any advice.
My problem is that I have this code for file download:

```
//***** DWN FILE *****       
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0); 
ob_get_clean();
ob_start();        
header("refresh: 1;"); 
header('Content-Type: application/jpg');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($my_allpath_dwn));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$my_imgfile.'"');              
@$file_dwnr = readfile($my_allpath_dwn);       

if ($file_dwnr) {$_SESSION['dwnstat'] = 'oki'; ob_flush(); flush();}
else {header("Location:./error_dwnmsg.html");}

if (connection_aborted()) {header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);}
exit;
```

Everything works OK if user click on SAVE button and so this script is completely proceed, file is saved and after it is page refreshed => No problem.
But if user click on CANCEL, when dialog with SaveAs is open, so no file is saved (which is OK, nevermind for me) but also page is not go to refresh. It looks to me that headers are sent and if they are terminated so nothing happen even if there is some other action to do.

I also try to ECHO with JS but no success. What only works is "header-Location", but if I put Location before exit so headers with Readfile are deleted and not send to browser, just only Location is send.

My question is, is there a way how to make redirect (page refresh) after Readfile Flush even user click on CANCEL in SaveAs dialog?
(I need to refresh the page whatever, but after Readfile Flush - after user see SaveAs Dialog and no matter if he click SAVE or CANCEL)
Thank you for advice.

**UPDATE:** I made one try => I separated code to 2 pages. One part for first page where user click on download button (input) and after it he is redirected (by Location"page2") to second page. On the second page which is now redirected, is code for this download (flush). And guess what......another strange behavior.....because when I click on first page on Download button so Header-Location is made only in background - I still see first page in browser (even Location was made) and also now comes Dialog SaveAs.....what the hell.....I have to go make some coffee myself, Iam confused to much....
I thought that if I use Header-Location so page goes to to another page and only after it is loaded content of second page (with all connected scripts, because second page call them, not first page).

Comment: When the user is asked whether to save the downloaded data to a file, the data is already being transmitted. The server doesn’t get a notice whether the user has saved the data in a file or canceled it. The only side effect of canceling is that when the data transmission is not already completed, it gets aborted.

Comment: GUMBO => Thanks for quick reply. I understand this, server sent the file and job is done. Ok, clear, but If you try my code you will find that if you click on SAVE so after file is saved the page go to refresh (by Header-refresh). But if you click on CANCEL so no file is saved (ok for me) and also page doesnt go to refresh. Maybe it is task for JS but why if user click on SAVE is page refreshed and if user click on CANCEL so is not refreshed - it looks to me like user CANCEL all sent headers??

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Prinsig => I have tested it in latest Firefox (34.0). I have also Opera and Chrome and IExplorer. I thought that this should be browser independent because it is PHP and server task. OK, I will try other browsers (I expect the same behavior with this). Thank you for little kick :)